# How can I make a class constructor be callable as a function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Some of the top level classes can be instantiated as well as called as a function (e.x. `new Number() and Number()`, `new Boolean() and Boolean()`, `new Array() and Array()`).

Usually this is used for type conversion or as a shortcut for instantiation.  I would like to be able to do the same thing:

```
public class Foo
{
  public function Foo():void
  {
    //do something
  }
}

public function Foo():Foo
{
  //do some stuff;
  return new Foo();
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

EDIT to clarify:

What I wanted to do originally was to create a logging class to interact with Flash/JavaScript, and be cross-browser compatible. I wanted to be able to use the log *function* as an alias of a method in the log *class*. This got me to wondering whether I could implement a custom casting function just because.  I've now realized it's not possible, but was fun to play with anyway.

Comment: it should work by default. it is called casting

Comment: @TiMeister I was hoping I could build in some custom handling. unfortunately it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: just curious, but what are you looking to achieve? is it more than just omitting the `new` keyword?

Comment: @gthmb I was hoping to alias a static member of a class used for debugging, as well as just plain curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define classes:

```
package [package name]
{
  public class Foo
  {
    public function Foo():void
    {
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

And you can define functions:

```
package [package name]
{
  public function Foo():Bar
  {
    return new Bar();
  }
}
```

But the classes and functions cannot have naming collisions. Otherwise you'll get a script error.

A custom casting function cannot be defined with the same name as the class, but it can be implemented under a different name:

```
package [package name]
{
  public function CastFoo(foo:*):Foo
  {
    //do stuff
    return Foo(foo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is correct:

```
public class Foo
{
  public function Foo():void
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

this is not:

```
public function Foo():Foo
{
  //do some stuff;
  return new Foo();
}
```

if you preceed Foo with "new":

```
new Foo();
```

you create a new instance of the Foo class.

if you don't:

```
Foo();
```

you get nothing - actually, you'll get a compiler error about missing arguments.

if you pass it a single argument:

```
var foo:Foo = Foo(bar);
```

you will cast "bar" as an instance of Foo.  The object to be cast must share a super class to be cast.  generally it's used for converting a more generic object type into a more specific object type - like casting event.target as a Sprite, or a DisplayObject returned by getChild into a MovieClip.

Comment: @Big MoMo I was hoping I could explicitly override how casting works. What confused me was that the `Array()` casting helper method could instantiate an array from a list of arguments, which is not *exactly* the same as casting other objects.

Comment: @zzz - actually, in strict mode, var bob:Array = Array(1, 2, 3) will give the same error.  if strict mode is off, you'll get a warning...  but i do know what you mean - other examples might be setTimeout or navigateToURL, which are always called with arguments rather than as 'new' instances...  not sure why they made the change with AS3, as you can do what you described with function Object created using prototype methods - 'new' forces and instance, otherwise it's just called...  anyway, interesting question

Comment: @Big MoMo `setTimeout` and `navigateToURL` are functions defined in the ECMA Script standard, they're the same for JavaScript. Same thing goes for the `Array()` function, it's an exception in being overloaded as an object.

Comment: This confusion is one of the reasons that they introduced the new syntax for casting: `var o:MyObj = (myInstance as MyObj)`.  It is recommended that folks avoid the old syntax (I'm not sure if it's officially deprecated at this point or not).

Comment: @zzz - i was just mentioning that they included utility function as part of certain packages (e.g., flash.utils.setTimeout), yet AFAICT this can't be recreated by developers using traditional package structures.  also, i don't think navigateToURL is part of the ECMA standard...
@lee - actually using "as" works differently than casting via constructor...
var bob:String = "1";
trace(bob as Number); // null...
trace(Number(bob)); // 1...
it's definitely not deprecated and shouldn't be.  both methods have a role.

Comment: @Big MoMo you can create top level functions within packages. They just need to be in their own file. They can also be defined within the `actions` of a flash file.  My mistake on `navigateToURL`, not really sure what I was thinking when i added that one in...